# React Three Fiber Forward events from scroll area to canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to build a similar demo to one of the examples

https://codesandbox.io/embed/r3f-moksha-f1ixt

My problem is as I start using a scroll area, all the pointer events are grabbed by the scroll area and the canvas doesn't receives them anymore, I tried using `pointer-events: none` but this disables the scroll event as well. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know whats the best way to keep the scrolling behavior while having the `onClick,onPointerOver,...etc` working on my mesh

A sandbox with my setup.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-pointer-events-z429y

Comment: If you want to drive threejs elements using the scroll, then give react-use-gesture a try. But if its HTML youre going to have to come up with a UX that doesn't have WebGL and HTML overlapping each other